# Tags that end in dashes produce weird searching/navigation behaviour

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I was searching for tags with 'new' in them on SO, and discovered a tag `[new-]` (1), which most likely doesn't belong. So I clicked through on it to see the question that's tagged with it. The URL I was taken to is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-.

The resulting list of questions is identical to the listing of questions with the tag `[new]`.

To find that single question, I have to use this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new--

This behaviour is also reproducible using the search box. Putting in '[new-]' results in the same list as if I had put in '[new]', and finally using '[new--]' I can find that single question.

Now, this isn't a huge deal because these tags need to be removed (right?), but this was not the behaviour I expected when clicking/searching. I also found `[init-]` by coincidence -- how many others are like this?

Comment: This reminds me of something - is there any easy way to find tags ending with some character? Or maybe even tags that only differ in their last character (e.g. singular vs. plural)?

Comment: @gf: Unfortunately, no, not that I'm aware of (if there was, I would make heavy use of it). Dashes are ignored in tag searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed, probably like 2 years ago - though that tag no longer exists.  Also, no tags can end like that anymore, the dashes on the end are automatically stripped if it's attempted.